# What is the definition of $n$-local commuting circuit?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, terminology-and-notation

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4570) paper and [this](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aa5fdb/pdf) one, they talk about commuting quantum circuits that are only composed of "$n$-local commuting circuits", typically for $n=2$ or $n=3$.

However they don't provide a definition of what it is.

The purpose of my question is: **what is a precise definition of "$n$-local commuting circuits"**

I found on [this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.TwoLocal.html) link that a 2-local circuit is composed of a layer of single qubit gates, followed by a layer of two qubit gates. Is an $n$-local circuit composed of $n-1$ layers of two qubit gates followed by a layer of single qubit gate?

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.NLocal.html

Answer (score 1):

A quantum circuit that has $N$ qudits is said to be $n$-local if the gates act nontrivially on *at most* $n$-qudits with $n\leq N$. As an example, here is a circuit of non-trivial gates acting on *at most* $2$-qubits in a system of $3$-qubits,

[image]

A commuting circuit is a quantum circuit in which the set of gates is pairwise commuting. See this references [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4570.pdf) for definitions, section 2.1. In particular, this paper is interestingly showing that there is great difference in simulating $2$ and $3$-local circuits.